# How to use select list in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to select an element from a select list in selenium using java with WebDriver - based syntax.

I've got the select list by

```
    elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//form[@action='inquiry/']/p/select[@name='myselect']"));
    if (elements.size() == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    if (guests != null) {
        //what do I do here?
    }
```

How do I do that?

Comment: what is 'guests !=null' do you mean 'elements!=null'?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
WebElement select = driver.findElement(By.name("myselect"));
Select dropDown = new Select(select);           
String selected = dropDown.getFirstSelectedOption().getText();
if(selected.equals(valueToSelect)){
    //already selected; 
    //do stuff
}
List<WebElement> Options = dropDown.getOptions();
for(WebElement option:Options){
    if(option.getText().equals(valueToSelect)) {
      option.click(); //select option here;       
    }               
}
```

If this is slower, then consider something like

```
dropDown.selectByValue(value);
or

dropDown.selectByVisibleText(text);
```

Answer (score 7):

A little side note which applies to Java:

In my case, when I was writing the test according the example of @nilesh, I got a strange error, that the constructor is invalid. My import was:

```
import org.openqa.jetty.html.Select;
```

If you happen to have similar errors, you have to correct that import to this:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
```

If you use this second import, everything will work.

Comment: I don't know about you, but personally, I hate java having multiple objects with identical names in different namespaces

Answer (score 1):

```
element = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//form[@action='inquiry/']/p/select[@name='myselect']/option[*** your criteria ***]"));
if (element != null) {
    element.click();
}
```

find the option, and then `click` it

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it like this :

//method to select an element from the dropdown

public void selectDropDown(String Value) {

```
    webElement findDropDown=driver.findElements(By.id="SelectDropDowm");
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(findDropDown));
    super.highlightElement(findDropDown);
    new Select(findDropDown).selectByVisibleText(Value);
}
```

//method to highlight the element

public void highlightElement(WebElement element) {

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) this.getDriver();
        js.executeScript(
                "arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);",
                element, "color: yellow; border: 3px solid yellow;");
        js.executeScript(
                "arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);",
                element, "");

    }

}
```