# I couldn't click the select dropdown on the website

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I couldn't click the  `depart`, `arrvie` dropdown menu form

> https://m.flyscoot.com/search

I tried to use Xpath to click them, But I got no luck:

```
@driver.find_element(:xpath,  "//~~~~~" ).click
```

And is there any way to let me fill the `date value` manually.

It's impractical to click the date by mouse, if I want to click the whole year.

The more practical solution is generating dates of whole  year then fill it in, but I could't get it with selenium `firefox driver`.

[image]

No luck by xpath with contains method:

```
@driver.find_element(:xpath, "//*[contains(text(),'Departure Airport')]")
```

> NoSuchElementError: Unable to locate element: 
>       [4] pry(#)> arrival = @driver.find_element(:xpath, "//*[contains(text(),'Departure Airport')]")
>       Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[contains(text(),'Departure
>   Airport')]"}
>       from [remote server] file:///var/folders/6d/*th4jpm90n1cx8h2l3kr49fr0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20150612-45453-15z20qu/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10271:in
>   `FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal*'
>
> webdriver
>
> ```
> ➜  workspace  gem list selenium-webdriver
>
> *** LOCAL GEMS ***
>
> selenium-webdriver (2.45.0)
> ```

Comment: can u post your URL?

Comment: @SarithaG Hi I updated it https://m.flyscoot.com/search

Answer (score 0):

To get departure you could  use(other ways too but I dont know what your source code so grabbing at strings here):

```
 arrival = find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Departure Airport')")
 departure find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Arrival Airport')")
```

As for setting the date, I would need to see your page source code. I would imagine that this could be accomplished using either straight JS, or Jquery with the `driver.execute_script('script here') command.`

Comment: No problem if you post your Page code I could get a clear idea

Comment: What is page code ? html source code ? i tried your solution, it still no luck on it, so sad

Comment: ok looked at page try this xpath "//div[@id='departureAirport-button]" and "//div[@id='arrivalAirport-button']"

Comment: But if you do `click` it won't pop up window :(

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to select airport:

```
    driver.get("https://m.flyscoot.com/search");

    // click on departure airport
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='departureAirport-button']"))
            .click();

    // Select any of option from the list of airports,Here i m selecting "sydney"
    driver.findElement(
            By.xpath("html/body/div[6]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[5]/div"))
            .click();

    //Click on done 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='Done']")).click();
```

And this is the code to select Date:

```
    // Click on Departure Date
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='date-depart-display']"))
            .click();


    // select date by clicking on particular date,Here i m selecting today's
    // date.
    driver.findElement(
            By.xpath(".//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[6]/a"))
            .click();
```

Comment: Have u tried your click function, it didn't show me the pop up on my browser. so sad!

Comment: Yah...i have tried. Its working perfectly. which browser are you using?

Comment: my browser is firefox :(

Comment: For me its working in all the browsers. It try to run it on different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, *wait for the departure dropdown to be visible* before interacting with it.

Also, use the [`Select` abstraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695652/how-to-use-select-list-in-selenium) and `selectByVisibleText()` (Java):

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

WebElement departure = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.ID("departureAirport")));
Select departureSelect = new Select(select);
departureSelect.selectByVisibleText("Hong Kong (HKG)");

WebElement arrival = driver.findElement(By.ID("arrivalAirport"));
Select arrivalSelect = Select(arrival);
arrivalSelect.selectByVisibleText("Melbourne (MEL)");
```

The same logic in Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://m.flyscoot.com/search")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
departure = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "departureAirport")))
departure = Select(departure)

departure.select_by_visible_text("Hong Kong (HKG)")

arrival = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("arrivalAirport"))
arrival.select_by_visible_text("Melbourne (MEL)")
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code, it partially works (at least the date is getting selected), But the selection on departure airport is not, I am still wondering why, Please see if this gives u any start. Mean while i shall get back if get some solution.

```
  Driver.navigate().to("https://m.flyscoot.com/search");
  Driver.findElement(By.id("departureAirport")).click();
  Select Element = new Select(Driver.findElement(By.id("departureAirport")));
  Element.selectByVisibleText("Singapore (SIN)");

  Driver.findElement(By.id("date-depart-display")).click();
  Thread.sleep(10);
  Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]/a")).click();
```