# How to handle Autosuggestion text field having dropdown list in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, xpath, autocomplete, dropdown, autosuggest

1. There is a text field called "Choose an Industry" on clicking inside it will show list of dropdown values.

Attaching the screen shot for ref[image]

Comment: You need `ActionChains` to set cursor over drop-down menu at first and then click on required option

Comment: Thanks Andersson. Could you please elaborate it so that it helps me in understanding

Comment: Specify programming language you use

Comment: @Andersson : I use Java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use select list in selenium?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695652/how-to-use-select-list-in-selenium)

Comment: This is just a simple `SELECT`. Have you tried the standard method for handling it? Please post the code you have tried after looking at the link.

Comment: @JeffC : String expectedValue = "Adverstising Services";

  WebElement button = driver.findElement(By
    .xpath(".//*[@id='select2-chooseInd-container']"));
  button.click();

  Select dropDown = new Select(button);
  List<WebElement> options = dropDown.getOptions();
  for (WebElement option : options) {
   if (option.getText().equals("expectedValue")) {
    option.click();

   }
  }

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues with the code you posted. With a little clean up it may work but there are methods provided by Selenium via `Select` that you should take advantage of.

```
String expectedValue = "Adverstising Services";
Select dropDown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='select2-chooseInd-container']")));
dropDown.selectByVisibleText(expectedValue);
```

You can read more about `Select` and the methods available in the docs, here: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html