# Verifying Drop Down values

Tags: selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

I have a below code

```
        String[] expected = {"Cancellation Context", "Cancellation Refund Type", "Claim Approval Letter Trigger", "Claim Cost Status", "Fronting  Insurer", "Minutes Of Delay For Automated Claim Email", "Payment Terms", "Payment Type","Product Offering","Quote Origin","Rate Override","Rating Point","Renewal Type","Second Payment From","Segment is required (th-TH)","Segments","Subsequent Payment Duration Type"};

        WebElement select = driver.findElement(AdminScreens.cmb_GlobalDDList);
        List<WebElement> allOptions = select.findElements(By.xpath(".//option"));

        int A1=expected.length;
        int A2=allOptions.size()-1;

        System.out.println("A1 and A1 are "+A1+ " and " +A2 );

        // make sure you found the right number of elements
        if (A1 != A2) {
            System.out.println("fail, wrong number of elements found");
        }
        // make sure that the value of every <option> element equals the expected value
        for (int i = 0; i < A1; i++) {
            String optionValue = allOptions.get(i).getAttribute("value");
            System.out.println("optionValues are "+optionValue);
            System.out.println("expected[i] are "+expected[i]);

            if (optionValue.equals(expected[i])) {
                System.out.println("passed on: " + optionValue);
            } else {
                System.out.println("failed on: " + optionValue);
            }
        }
```

When i run the code my code is failed and displayed the result set as below

```
A1 and A1 are 17 and 17
optionValues are 0
expected[i] are Cancellation Context
failed on: 0
optionValues are 42
expected[i] are Cancellation Refund Type
failed on: 42
optionValues are 39
expected[i] are Claim Approval Letter Trigger
failed on: 39
optionValues are 28
expected[i] are Claim Cost Status
failed on: 28
optionValues are 25
expected[i] are Fronting  Insurer
failed on: 25
optionValues are 40
expected[i] are Minutes Of Delay For Automated Claim Email
failed on: 40
optionValues are 29
expected[i] are Payment Terms
failed on: 29
optionValues are 14
expected[i] are Payment Type
failed on: 14
optionValues are 24
expected[i] are Product Offering
failed on: 24
optionValues are 11
expected[i] are Quote Origin
failed on: 11
optionValues are 43
expected[i] are Rate Override
failed on: 43
optionValues are 15
expected[i] are Rating Point
failed on: 15
optionValues are 20
expected[i] are Renewal Type
failed on: 20
optionValues are 41
expected[i] are Second Payment From
failed on: 41
optionValues are 26
expected[i] are Segment is required (th-TH)
failed on: 26
optionValues are 44
expected[i] are Segments
failed on: 44
optionValues are 38
expected[i] are Subsequent Payment Duration Type
failed on: 38
```

I suspect the line of code

```
List<WebElement> allOptions = select.findElements(By.xpath(".//option"));
```

which i used is wrong...Because am taking option in xpath which will fetch my option value and compare with my array. Can anyone help me out how can i take the text instead of option value. So that i can compare the text with my array text

Comment: can you add the relevant html code too?

Comment: try `getText()` instead of `getAttribute("value")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use select list in selenium?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695652/how-to-use-select-list-in-selenium)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the attribute `value` for the `<option />` has a unique code (eg `0`) for that option instead of the text for that option.

Assuming your drop down code is somewhat like

`<option value="0">Cancellation Context</option>`

you may have to change the line

`String optionValue = allOptions.get(i).getAttribute("value");`

to

`String optionValue = allOptions.get(i).getText();`